# Is this sentence a contradiction in terms?

Tags: vocabulary, semantics

The sentence is "The amendment has the effect of disqualifying the unqualified"
Is it accurate to call the amendment a contradiction in terms?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is nothing wrong with the amendment. “Unqualified” and “disqualified” are not synonyms, and it’s perfectly possible to be unqualified for a job but not to be disqualified from holding it. Just for example, a politician may be unqualified for the job of head of state, but not be disqualified from holding that position.

In any case, even if they were synonyms, then the amendment would be a tautology rather than a contradiction in terms. It’s saying the same thing twice, not saying two different and mutually contradictory things.